# chrome.tabs.executeScript not working on pc and works on mac

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing an extension on the mac and when I tried it on pc it doesn't work properly.  When i check content scripts on the MAC i can see the scripts being loaded and on PC content scripts are blank.  Here is the code.  Is there  a difference between mac and pc chrome as far as writing extensions?

popup.js

```
function click(e) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
      {code:"var option ='" + e.target.id + "'"},function() {chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
        { file: "jquery.js" },function() {chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
      { file: "SetKace.js" })})});
  window.close();
}
```

manifest.json

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
  ],
```

Comment: No, there is no difference in this API. Are you trying to actively debug it? If Dev Tools are open, this may hijack the "current tab" concept.

Comment: I am executing in alert in SetKace.js and it doesn't popup on pc but it does on mac.  Another obervation is that if i just run code in execute script it does execute but when i nest injecting few scripts it doesn't.